# background value if empty

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have

```
property Background: TPicture read FBackground write SetBackground;
```

if nothing is ever assiged to it, what would the value be of background?

i have tried

```
if Background = NULL  then

begin
...
..
...
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. When the field is created in the constructor and FBackground is assigned, then use:

```
if FBackground.Graphic = nil then
```

Or:

```
if not Assigned(FBackground.Graphic) then
```

---

If the Graphic is assigned, then use:

```
if FBackground.Graphic.Empty then
```

---

And if both property and field are unassigned then use:

```
if FBackground = nil then
```

Or:

```
if not Assigned(FBackground) then
```

---

All of the above combined:

```
if (FBackground = nil) or (FBackground.Graphic = nil) or FBackground.Graphic.Empty then
```